# How to reshape this dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, reshape

I need to reshape the dataframe like this:

```
  nam  code date1 date2
0   a     1   1/1   1/2
1   b     3   3/4   4/5
```

but `df.stack` seems useless in this situation.

Desired output:

```
  nam  code date
0   a     1  1/1
1   a     1  1/2
2   b     3  3/4
3   b     3  4/5
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use `lreshape`, [`sort_values`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.sort_values.html) by column `nam`, [`reindex_axis`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.reindex_axis.html) columns and last [`reset_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html):

```
print pd.lreshape(df, {'date': ['date1', 'date2']})
        .sort_values('nam')
        .reindex_axis(['nam','code','date'], axis=1)
        .reset_index(drop=True)

  nam  code date
0   a     1  1/1
1   a     1  1/2
2   b     3  3/4
3   b     3  4/5
```

Another solution with [`melt`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.melt.html), [`drop`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Panel.drop.html) for droping column `variable`, [`sort_values`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.sort_values.html) by column `nam` and last [`reset_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html):

```
print pd.melt(df, id_vars=['nam','code'], value_name='date')
        .drop('variable', axis=1)
        .sort_values('nam')
        .reset_index(drop=True)

  nam  code date
0   a     1  1/1
1   a     1  1/2
2   b     3  3/4
3   b     3  4/5
```

EDIT:

[`lreshape`](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/master/pandas/core/reshape.py#L857) is now undocumented, but is possible in future will by removed ([with pd.wide_to_long too](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/15003#issuecomment-324625271)).

Possible solution is merging all 3 functions to one - maybe `melt`, but now it is not implementated. Maybe in some new version of pandas. Then my answer will be updated.

Comment: I didn't know about lreshape. Is this documented?

Comment: try in `spyder` `help (pd.lreshape)`, but it is not well documented yet.

Comment: Well certainly better than reshaping the numpy arrays and turning back to the dataframe. Good to know. Thanks. :)

Comment: Per the doc string (using `??`): `def lreshape(data, groups, dropna=True, label=None):
    """
    Reshape long-format data to wide. Generalized inverse of DataFrame.pivot`