# How do you concatenate two differently named columns together in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, concatenation

I'd like to create a new dataframe where A and B or kept but column B is renamed and column A and C get repeated underneath it but C's value's being placed into the renamed column C (D).

```
df =  A      B   C
    'bob'    1   4
    'john'   2   5
    'mick'   3   6
```

This is what the new dataframe should look like.

```
new_df = A      D
       'bob'    1  
       'john'   2  
       'mick'   3  
       'bob'    4  
       'john'   5  
       'mick'   6
```

Comment: Post what you've tried so far.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to reshape this dataframe](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37118464/how-to-reshape-this-dataframe)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

***Alternative-1:***

Use [`lreshape`](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/master/pandas/core/reshape.py#L804) to convert from wide to long formatted `DF`:

```
pd.lreshape(df, {'D': ['B', 'C']})
```

[image]

---

***Alternative-2:***

If you want to perform concatenation, then do:

```
df = df.set_index(['A'])
pd.concat([df['B'], df['C']]).reset_index(name='D')
```

[image]